# Dynamic value to JMS PTP fields in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have been trying for weeks now to find a way to handle jmeter script using only single thread group & pass connection variables dynamically by CSV file in which I'm failing terribly. I have multiple value in place of QueueConnection few test cases have message properties as well. I would like to find a way to eternalize is & use single thread group to achieve it.
Check the screenshot an example of variable which should take value dynamically from a file is what I'm expecting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMJlW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use CSV file, you will have to go for [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#introduction) instead.

And in the JMS P2P Sampler you need to use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the properties values

Something like:

[image]

The properties along with their respective values can be:

- put into *user.properties* file like:

  ```
  queueConnectionFactory=ConnectionFactory
  ```
- passed via `-J` command-line arguments like

  ```
   jmeter -JqueueConnectionFactory=ConnectionFactory
  ```
- put into a separate .properties file, in this case you will need to "feed" this file to JMeter via `-q` command-line argument like:

  ```
   jmeter -q /path/to/your/custom/JMS.properties -t test.jmx ...
  ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

Comment: Looks good let me try it out & see how it works. I'm new to jmeter so would have to go through the documents. Thanks for the idea.